# Is there any online lectures or workshops available for ROS other than ROS/wiki?

Tags: ros, 3d-navigation, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

require details about practical books, lectures and workshops available online to learn ROS for visual navigation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201175/is-there-any-online-lectures-or-workshops-available-for-ros-other-than-ros/wiki?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- List of books dedicated for ROS http://wiki.ros.org/Books
- List of courses http://wiki.ros.org/Courses

You may find even more useful materials that are available through the top page of ROS wiki http://wiki.ros.org/.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1